# Qt slot not called

Tags: qt, signals-slots

I am trying to connect to a signal in this way:

```
QObject::connect(myObj, SIGNAL(mySignal(std::list<MyClass*> myList)), this, SLOT(mySlot(std::list<MyClass*> myList)));
```

the slot is not invoked. Is that wrong? Can I use `std::list` in a `signal/slot` pair?

**EDIT:** same pair without parameters work

```
class TestThread : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    .....
    protected:
     virtual void run();

private:
    std::list<MyClass*> myList;

signals:
    void mySignal(std::list<MyClass*>&);



};
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE (std::list<MyClass*>)
```

EDIT:

```
void mySlot(const std::list<MyClass*> &);

void 
MyManager::mySlot(const std::list<MyClass*> &theList)
{
    std::cout << "mySlot " << std::endl;
}

void mySignal(const std::list<MyClass*> &theList);

TestThread ::TestThread (std::list<MyClass*>&theList, QObject *parent)
    :  QThread(parent),  myList(theList)
{


}



void
TestThread ::run() 
{
   ...
   emit mySignal(myList);
}
```

in the end:

```
QObject::connect(threadObj, SIGNAL(mySignal(std::list<MyClass*>)), this, SLOT(mySlot(std::list<MyClass*>)));
```

Comment: Where is the class that has the slot?

Comment: @cbamber85 in the Main thread. The signal is emitted by TestThread

Comment: Show us the declaration then.

Comment: Show us the `MyManager` header, and why isn't `mySignal` in `TestThread` scope?

Comment: You will usually need to move an object to the main application thread so it is part of the event loop. Could that be the issue here? Maybe reduce your signal to a no-argument version to verify if registering the metatype is really an issue. Then see http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qobject.html#moveToThread

Comment: @pmr no argument signal is fired

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only need the type, not the actual name of the variable.

```
QObject::connect(myObj, SIGNAL(mySignal(std::list<MyClass*>)), this, SLOT(mySlot(std::list<MyClass*>)));
```

If you were trying to send an `int`, you would use

```
SIGNAL(mySignal(int))
```

Not

```
SIGNAL(mySignal(int x))
```

Edit: As @Chris points out, mismatching the `const` and `&` shouldn't make a difference.

The code below correctly emits the signal and receives it in the other thread.  If you don't use `qRegisterMetaType`, you get a runtime warning message telling you to do so.

```
class A
{
public:
    A(): i(1) {}
    int i;
};

class T : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    void run()
    {
       emit mySignal(myList);
    }

    std::list<A*> myList;

signals:
    void mySignal(const std::list<A*>&);
};

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE (std::list<A*>)
class Test: public QDialog
{   
    Q_OBJECT//this macro flags the class for the moc tool

public:
    Test()
    {
       qRegisterMetaType<std::list< A* > >("std::list<A*>");

       t = new T;
       connect(t, SIGNAL(mySignal(std::list<A*>)), this, SLOT(mySlot(std::list<A*>)));
       printf("after connect\n");

       t->start();
    }

public slots:
    void mySlot(const std::list<A*>& list){printf("mySlot");}

protected:
    T* t;
};
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, but It does not work. Any other hint?

Comment: *What* doesn't work? How are you emitting the signal? Are there error messages? Compiler warnings? What is the slot declaration?

Comment: I emit the signal like emit mySignal(myList). No warning message. I am on Visual Studio 2005. need I to add some compiler paramter to get compiler warnings?

Comment: You should get a warning at connect() time, on the debug channel. One problem is that your signal passes a non-const ref: std::list<MyClass*>&. The rule is s(T), s(const T&) -> SIGNAL(s(T)), but s(T&) -> SIGNAL(s(T&)). Then also the slot must take a non-const ref. Passing a non-const ref. only makes sense in *very* *few* cases though, so you probably want to make that a const ref.

Comment: should  I declare like SIGNAL(mySignal(std::list<MyClass*>&)) ?

Comment: `SIGNAL(mySignal(const std::list<MyClass*>&))` is the signature that matches your `signal` and `slot` definitions.  You also need to do the same for the `SLOT` part of the connection.

Comment: signal/slot connections absolutely **do not** require the const or reference qualifiers in order to work.  If you look at the SIGNAL macro it strips them away before processing them.  Additionally your slot doesn't not have to take a const ref even if your signal emits one.

Comment: still it does not invoke the slot!!

Comment: As @FrankOsterfeld points out, if a problem is detected at the time of the `connect` call, a warning message should be printed.  It would be handy to see what that message says.

Comment: @Chris: non-const references are an exception to that rule. There the & *is* needed. signal T and signal/slot const T& are compatible, T and T& are not.

Answer (score 7):

If the signal emiting object and the receiving object are located in different threads, you have to register your meta-type with [qRegisterMetaType](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qmetatype.html#qRegisterMetaType)  before using it in an emit. In your case:

```
qRegisterMetaType<std::list< MyClass* > >("std::list<MyClass*>");
```

somewhere at the start of your app should do it.

Comment: As long as the command is called before the first emission, it's OK.

Comment: metatype registration is only needed for queued connections (i.e. among threads, or when explicitly passed to the connect)

Comment: First, you should try it at the start of your main, just after creating you QApplication. If it solve your problem, you could try it in your thread constructor, I don't see why it would'nt work.

Comment: +1 for identifying the thread-boundary problem early (even earlier than it was mentioned that there was threading going on, if I remember correctly). I wrote an example demonstrating that using `qRegisterMetaType` allows the connection to succeed.  If there is still a problem, it lies elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

If you have derived from `QObject`, added the `Q_OBJECT` macro to the class header, and made sure the signals and slots involved have the correct access modifiers (i.e. `public slots`) - then it may mean that you need to add:

```
#include <QMetaType>
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE( std::list<MyClass*> );
```

Comment: You're right, but it looks like he's emitting across thread boundaries, and Qt::AutoConnection switches to QueuedConnection when the objects involved are not in the same thread.